# Looking for a specific bibliographystyle for bibtex in german language

Tags: bibtex, citing

I am looking for a specific bibliographystyle for german language, I tried a lot of different styles, but I didn't find the right one.

The style should list up my bibtex entrys **in order of appereance** in the text and **just with numbers in brackets**

Furthermore the bibliographystyle should change the word 'and' for listing up several authors by a ',' or the german word 'und'. And the bibliographystyle should write for books for wich an edition is noted, the german word Edition. Last but not least the bibliographystyle shouldn't change the order of the firstname and the secondname of an author.

desired result :

[1] author1 **,** author2 **,** author3 **und** author4 **.** booktitle **.** publishername **,** editionNumer **.** **Edition** **,** year **.**

[2] ....

[3] ....

If there is a bibliographystyle like this or similar too what I'm looking for, please share it with me. Thank you!

Comment: Why not simply using `biblatex`?

Comment: I'm afraid your specifications leave a lot of ambiguity. E.g., should first and middle names be abbreviated? And, how should entries of type `@article` and `@misc`, to mention just two entry types, be formatted? Or does your bibliography contain only entries of type `@book`?

Comment: By now I am using the bibliographstyle unsrt, which fulfills all my requirements except the german words for 'and' & 'edition'. Is there any way to modify the style?

Comment: Or is there a same style like unsrt specific for german language?

Comment: You could try `un­srt­din`.

Comment: unsrtdin solves the problem with the 'and'. But it will print for the edition just the number without the word Edition behind. And it will also print the lastname first.

Comment: It all will be easier with `biblatex`.

Comment: OK. Than I should move to biblatex. Thank you all!